# Split string with unexpected behaviour?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, split

I am reading a csv file and I use a split on every line but I do not fully understand the behavior.

csv file:

```
id;name;number
1111;foo \nbar;2.00
2222;a 0,25;1.00
```

code:

```
for file in csvs:
    with open(file, encoding = "utf8") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            if isinstance(row, str):
                print(row)
            else:
                print(row[0].split(";"))
```

This yields:

```
['number', 'name', 'price']
['1111', 'foo \\nbar', '2.00']
['2222', 'a 0']
```

but I expected the last line to be:

```
['2222', 'a 0,25', '1.00']
```

Comment: The csv reader will assume your values are separated by commas if you do not tell it different. So the reader gives you a row with `2222;a 0` as the first element; and then you split it by `;` subsequently. If you want to manually split each line, there is no need to use `csv.reader`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the delimiter arg to `csv.reader` to split on semicolons instead of commas:

```
for file in csvs:
    with open(file, encoding = "utf8") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f,delimiter=";")
        for row in reader:
            print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use split() on its own. This is some code that should work (untested), assuming csv is the raw string data:

```py
C = csv.split("\n")
Y = []
for X in C:
    Y.append(X.split(";"))
```

Comment: Better to use the `csv` module correctly, as it properly handles columns that contain the delimiter.

Comment: Sorry I really don't know much about this, am using my phone and it's 00:08 where I live. Please feel free to downvote and ignore this.